# Proving using AM-GM inequality

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality

If $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$, and $x>y$, how to show
$(x-y)^{((x-y)/(2x-y))}\times (x+y)^{((x)/(2x-y))}>x$?

I know I have to use AM-GM inequality, but it is not clear how.

Comment: Please comment before downvote.

Comment: I'm sorry people have rushed to "attack" your question without engaging with you in any way first.  Unfortunately, that happens often here.  Also, one possible explanation for the downvotes is that you asked the same question more than once.  The site rules prohibit this.  We usually only want a question asked once rather than having duplicates.  You could have deleted this version of the question first, and then posted the other question.  Or alternatively, you could have edited the text in this question instead of posting a new one.  I hope this helps, and I hope you get help!

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also note that you must not repost your questions just because the original one has been ill-received. Do you have any own thoughts on the problem at hand?

Comment: If $y=0$ then the left hand side equals $x$, so I think that $y$ should be positive.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the following.

Beasause of reasons which I write in my comment and which are written in the [duplicate of the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1305228/is-there-a-math-basis-for-what-i-observe-in-simulations), I assume that $y>0$.

Since $x+(x-y)=2x-y$, we have to prove that

$$X=(1-y/x)^{((x-y)/(2x-y))} (1+y/x)^{(x/(2x-y))}>1.$$

Put $t=y/x$. Then $0<t<1$ and $$X=(1-t)^{(1-t)/(2-t)} (1+t)^{1/(2-t)}.$$

So we have to prove that

$$Y=(1-t)^{(1-t)} (1+t)>1.$$

But $(1-t)^{(1-t)}>1-t(1-t)$ by Bernoulli inequality. Then

$$Y>(1-t(1-t))(1+t)=(1-t+t^2)(1+t)> (1-t+t^2-t^3+t^4-\dots)(1+t)=1.$$