# Is there a math basis for what I observe in simulations?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality

I am stuck in my research with the following problem which occurs when proving a theorem.

> > If $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^+$ and $x>y$, is it true that
> >     $(x-y)^{((x-y)/(2x-y))}\times (x+y)^{(x/(2x-y))}>x$?

I plugged in a range of values for $x$ and $y$ and always found this holds. However I am not sure how one can prove a statement of this nature? Can someone help me with this?

Comment: @K.Dutta You should have marked the other question as a duplicate.  This version I think gives more insight into the user's background on the question.

Comment: @user46944 No. The other one gives more insight and makes this one look like an attempt at obfuscating homework, as the other states "I know I have to use AM-GM". How should you "know" that when you are "researching"?

Comment: @AlexR You have absolutely no proof that your accusations against the OP of trying to hide homework are true.  The "evidence" you've presented is hardly rock solid.  Try to remember that this site isn't supposed to be a witch hunt against all users with questions regarding if their question is homework or not.  Sure, we don't want to help users cheat, but that doesn't mean going around throwing ridiculous accusations without solid proof.

Comment: @user46944 1 - "Ridiculous" is opinion-based in this scenario. 2 - I don't accuse, carefully check my wording: "makes (...) look like". The rest of my comment merely justifies _what_ makes this one look like such an attempt. In no way am I accusing anything or anyone.

Comment: what is in the case $x=-5,y=-100$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner: I guess it is only for $\mathbb{R}^+$.

Comment: yes i also but this condition must be added